# Why doesn't my code work for N queens?

Tags: python, adjacency-matrix, n-queens

I got this code and basically if I input: 0 1 then 1 will be assigned to position 0 1 on this adjacency matrix I named as chessboard.Problem is for a chesboard of size 4x4,if I entered

```
1 0, 
3 1,
0 2,
2 3
```

it is supposed to output

```
[[0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

but I get an error of 'int' object does not support item assignment in this line:

```
chessboard[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 1
```

This is my code.

```
N = int ( input (" Enter N: ") ) # Makes an empty chessboard of size N by N
chessboard = N*[0]
for row in range (N) :
    chessboard[row]=N*[0]
    print(chessboard)
    # This while loop asks the user for input N times and checks that it ’s     validity and places the queens
    inputCount = 0
    while inputCount < N:
         pos = input (" Please input the Queen position ")
        pos = pos.split () # Cast the input as integers
        pos [0] = int (pos [0])
        pos [1] = int (pos [1])
# If the input is out of range , inform the user , decrement the counter set the input to 0 1
    if pos [0] < 0 or pos [0] >N-1 or pos [1] < 0 or pos [1] >N-1:
        print (" Invalid position ")
        pos [0] = pos [1] = 0
        inputCount=inputCount-1
    else :# Uses the input to place the queens
        chessboard[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 1
    inputCount += 1
print ( chessboard )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
chessboard = N*[0]
for row in range (N) :
    chessboard[row]=N*[0]
    print(chessboard)

    # here you're still in the chessboard init loop

    inputCount = 0
    while inputCount < N:
```

you're starting your processing *while initializing `chessboard`*, not *after* it has started.

Since `chessboard` is first a list of integers (why that?), replaced by a list of list of integers in your loop, and your loop is only executing the first iteration, you're getting this error.

you need to unindent everything from `print(chessboard)`

But it's even better to just initialize `chessboard` without a loop like this (using list comprehension in the outer loop instead of multiplication, to generate a separate reference of each row):

```
chessboard = [[0]*N for _ in range(N)]
```